# Incorrect time when sleep.d script is launched

Tags: shell-script

My OS is Linux Slackware 14.2. I wanted to automatically block my attempts to work at unproductive night hours. So I created the script /etc/pm.d/sleep.d/time.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

hour=$(date +%_H)

if (( hour < 6 || hour >= 21)); then
    /sbin/poweroff
fi
```

It will be automatically launched every time when the laptop lid is opened. The problem is: if the lid is closed between 21 and 6 o'clock and opened at the different time, when the script is launched, the time is still unchanged for a little period of time, and the computer turns off.

How to make the script wait until the time updates?

Comment: Why don't you put a fraction of `sleep` at the beginning of your script? it might help: `sleep 0.1`

Comment: @Ravexina Will try.

Comment: Let me know what happened ;)